# How to insert a json text file to a sqlite in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

There is about 183 set of tweets which I'm tring to insert values from a particular key which has the same name as the column. The problem is I was loop the 'file' and printed out which show all the set of dictionaries I wanted, but when I used json.loads(i) it catch only 1 dict.

```
 import sqlite3

 import json
 conn = sqlite3.connect('csc455.db')
 c = conn.cursor()

 tweet = 
         '''create table tweet(
                              created_at nvarchar(500),
                              id_str varchar(500),
                              text varchar(500),
                              source text,
                              in_reply_to_user_id integer null,
                              in_reply_to_screen_name nvarchar(3000) null,
                              in_reply_to_status_id integer null,
                             retweet_count boolean,
                             contributors nvarchar(200) null
                              ); '''
 c.execute('''drop table tweet''')
 c.execute(tweet)

 read = open('Tweet1_Assignment4 (1).txt')
 file = read.readline().strip('\n').split('EndOfTweet')
 read.close()

 for i in file:
     jsonn = json.loads(i)
```

I'm sorry I'm pretty new to this environment.

Comment: read data from the file for each individual row and execute the sql command to save the data in db

Comment: I have to do it this way though, that's the instruction from my professor. This is just the first part. I try to get the loop part done first and inserting it in my local table to contain value of tweet from tweet file. When use json.loads(i) it only catch one tweet from 183 which I couldn't solve it.

Comment: @yeah you can do this way also, for each row in the database to add, collect that data from file and  then for that data use `insert` command  and `execute` it

Comment: Could you paste yours .txt file and share with us?

Comment: I can but I don't know how to do it here.

Comment: The file is in the same structure as URL file like this ..  {"created_at":"Tue Nov 05 00:00:04 +0000 2013","id":....... and so on and stopwith 'EndOfTweet' I think it is downloading from twitter site.

Answer (score 0):

It reads only one line because of 
...read.**readline()**.strip('\n')...
it should be

```
f = open('Tweet1_Assignment4 (1).txt')
file = f.read().strip('\n').split('EndOfTweet')
f.close()
```

`.readline()` reads one line
`.read()` reads all file content (that's why i changed variable name to f from read, 'cause you were shadowing methods name)

Comment: The whole file is one line. I try to do it multple ways. But I couldn't get over when I loop content for ex.  'for i in file' it will show every spilt part if I print it out. On the other hand, if I loaded it with json.loads(i) under loop it only catch the last one.